# Post comment programmatically to Reddit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to programmatically post a comment to Reddit using the Snoocore library.

Here's my code:

```
    function postComment() {
        var commentText = document.getElementById("response").value;
        reddit('/api/comment').post({
            api_type: 'json',
            thing_id: getUrlVars()['link'],
            text: commentText
        });
    }
```

I am calling it with an onclick event in a button of mine.

```
<input type="button" value="Save" id="save-button" data-role="button" onclick="postComment()">
```

The function postComment() executes, but I get the following json response:

```
>>> Reddit Response:

{
  "json": {
    "errors": [
      [
        "USER_REQUIRED",
        "please sign in to do that",
        null
      ]
    ]
  }
}

>>> Endpoint URL: https://ssl.reddit.com/api/comment

>>> Endpoint method: POST

>>> Arguments: {
....
```

Now, I know the credentials are correct.

I am able to login in a separate section of the code:

```
reddit.raw('http://www.reddit.com/api/me.json').get({
            }).then(function(data) {
                mainReddit(data);
            });
```

But not post a comment.

Why is this not working? I am logged in, why does Reddit think I am not?

EDIT:

**I added the uh parameter, and now I'm receiving 403 errors.**

uh: data.data.modhash

I also changed my code to this:

```
        function postComment() {
            reddit.raw('http://www.reddit.com/api/me.json').get({
            }).then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var commentText = document.getElementById("response").value;
                reddit('/api/comment').post({
                    api_type: 'json',
                    thing_id: getUrlVars()['link'],
                    text: commentText,
                    uh: data.data.modhash
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: In your `console.log(data);` are you getting data suggesting that you're authenticated?

Comment: Also, I'm curious if changing `then` to `done` changes anything.

Comment: POST https://ssl.reddit.com/api/comment 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: So are you getting valid data in console.log(data) or not?

Comment: I am getting valid data in console.log(data) whether I use .then or .done. It always returns an object with my user data. So it SEEMS like it should be working.

Comment: Got it, full name included t3_, and I didn't have that as part of my value.

Answer (score 1):

When you are posting to Reddit, you have to insure that you have the full thing_id - that means you have to include t1_ and t3_ depending on what type of comment it is.